# Set datagrid column visibility as collapsed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application, where i set create datagrids dynamically and set the itemsource as datatable.

```
DataGrid grdTemp = new DataGrid();                   
grdTemp.FrozenColumnCount = 2;
grdTemp.ItemsSource = dtTemp.DefaultView;
```

I would like to set some of the columns visibility as collapsed. However,  after setting the itemsource when I check grdTemp.Columns its shows count as 0. The item source is set correctly and is displayed on UI. But I am not able to set the column visibility. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the event of the DataGrid to collapse the column.

```
DataGrid grdTemp = new DataGrid();                   
grdTemp.FrozenColumnCount = 2;
grdTemp.ItemsSource = dtTemp.DefaultView;
grdTemp.AutoGeneratingColumn += new EventHandler<DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs>(grdTemp_AutoGeneratingColumn);
```

and inside that event, you can get the column and its properties.

```
void grdTemp_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Column.Header == "ID") //you can add your check for the column
              e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Hope this helps you